# Not able to retrieve session/request scope values using JSTL

Tags: jstl

In my xhtml page am setting values in some `myValue` variable. Code is as below,

```
<body>
<c:set var="myValue" value="someValue" scope="request"></c:set>`
</body>
```

Am hitting a login.jsp (Login page) from this xhtml page and trying to print the value on my login.jsp as below,

```
myValue ID retrieved from request <c:out value="${param.myValue}" />
```

This is not printing `someValue`. I also checked by putting it in session scope like below,

```
<c:set var="myValue" value="someValue" scope="session"></c:set>
```

Even this is not working

And in login.jsp,

```
myValue ID retrieved from session <c:out value="${sessionScope.myValue}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have just ${myValue}, as param.myValue means to find value from URL params.